# What were the likely lives of the highly creative or intellectually gifted people in declining or primitive civilizations?

Tags: biographical-details

People living in certain regions throughout history produced little to none recorded intellectual achievements.
Assuming that highly creative individuals existed in these regions, are there any historical accounts of their lives?

If we have such accounts are there any similarities in their lives?

Comment: It depends how you define gifted or creative. A creative farmer may be generating hoards of extra crops through good land management or whatever, but it's not necessarily the sort of thing that would be written down.

Comment: This reminds me of Gauss showing early talent with math and his father basically ignoring this -- it was not until Gauss was 8 that his talent was nurtured by a school teacher but this could easily have not happened if Gauss had been born a century earlier or in a different place.